# To multiplications using parseFloat jQuery

Tags: jquery

**Adding additional cost to output**

This is taking the total shipping costs, splitting the individual packages and outputting a total of the combined packages.  Which works but I would like to (in addition too) add 20% to the output.

```
 var adjusted_total = parseFloat(rate[1]) * custom_packages;
```

Comment: IMO, your question is awfully confusing (I'm assuming because you're not providing enough info). What is the first snippet of code's intent, and the second? What's in jQuery(this).val() originally (or what is rate[0] and rate[1])? Where's the total of combined packages you speak of (is it adjusted_total?)?

Comment: Again, to simplify, I need to keep this bit, and add another 20% on top of the output.   var adjusted_total = parseFloat(rate[1]) * custom_packages;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var adjusted_total = parseFloat(rate[1]) * custom_packages; //if adjusted_total  = 100
adjusted_total *= 1.2 // will give 120
```

Comment: I tried what you have minus the = So what you did there was take that var and multiply it again and the original * is what's being multiplied?  And it worked, thanks!